# Typescript Type checking on React not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Something very strange is happening to my code.

I decided to use typescript on React to have more control over my code but unfortunately it is not throwing me any errors or warnings when I pass a different type than I had previously specified. (by the way, I am using styled components)

Example:

```
const buttonText = 123

export const ExampleComponent: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ButtonComponent text={buttonText} />
    </div>
  );
```

On the button's component, however, I am defining an Interface so my Class can expect a pre-defined type:

```
interface Props {
  text: string;
}

export const ButtonComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ text }) => {
  return <Button>{text}</Button>;
};
```

However, since my `buttonText` variable **is an integer** I expected to get a warning or some error, but instead nothing happened.

This is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable"
    ],
    "removeComments": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@config/*": ["src/config/*"],
      "@interfaces/*": ["src/interfaces/*"],
      "@styles/*": ["src/styles/*"],
      "@const/*": ["src/const/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./src",
    "./webpack/webpack.config.ts"
  ],
}
```

Do someone know why this is happening?

Comment: Pasting your code into an existing React project, I do get compiler errors `(JSX attribute) Props.text: string
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
App.tsx(12, 3): The expected type comes from property 'text' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'`

Comment: That's weird. maybe it's a webpack configuration?

Comment: I would think your webpack config should include your typescript code, not the other way around. Have you tried starting a new react project via `create-react-app` with the typescript template?

Comment: Actually this project of mine is not a CRA. I tried creating my own webapck and starting from scratch.

Comment: Then you most likely need to post your webpack config file too, as there is something wrong, possibly there.